# How to pass a differentiable function explicitly to T.grad?

Tags: theano

Can you please tell, how can I pass various differentiable function to T.grad? I want something like this:

```
x = T.dscalar('x')

ellipic_paraboloid = x ** 2 + y ** 2
hyperbolic_paraboloid = x ** 2 - y ** 2

gradients = theano.function([function_of_xy, x, y], T.grad(function_of_xy, gx, gy))

gradients(ellipic_paraboloid, 1, 1)
gradients(hyperbolic_paraboloid, 1, 1)
```